# Start activity from IntentService does not work in Android 12

Tags: android, push-notification, intentservice, android-workmanager, android-12

Quick background: I have updated my latest `targetSdkVersion` to the latest Android 31

I have a service class that gets executed after a notification is clicked from the notification tray, it contains below code:

```
public class NotificationClickListener extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Intent myIntentFromPendingIntent = intent;
        //insert some necessary code

        myIntentFromPendingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(myIntentFromPendingIntent); //this line here gets executed but the application or the activity wasn't opened after this line
    }
```

The PendingIntent is created like the below code after a message is received

```
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(appContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, myNotification);
```

I am not getting any error logs or any relevant trace logs, the only logs I am seeing is

```
    D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
```

I have browsed some documentation and have stumbled upon [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts), and there were some listed exceptions, one of which is that when "The app has an activity in the back stack of the foreground task." So I was expecting that my activity would be started (given that my application was paused in the background)

---

Can anyone help me locate the issue? Is it possible to still fix this using IntentService?

Or is it now necessary to migrate using WorkManager? If so, can you also please leave a good reference to check out.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I was expecting that my activity would be started (given that my application was paused in the background)

FWIW it appears that it does not qualify for the rule that you cited: "The app has an activity in **the back stack of the *foreground* task**." (emphasis added) — your app is in the background, not the foreground.

> I have a service class that gets executed after a notification is clicked from the notification tray, it contains below code:

Have your notification launch the activity directly. "Trampolines" like this [are banned once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 31 or higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines).

Comment: let me try launching the activity directly, should be as direct as ```PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(appContext, 0, intentAsMyExpectedActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);```, right?

Comment: @Zerosero: It would be `getActivity()` instead of `getService()`, but otherwise that looks good.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you very much! This is now okay :D

Comment: @CommonsWare About notification trampoline - how do you do push click analytics, when the pushes lead to external application/activity (for example: push leading to google play)?

Comment: @Kocus: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have actually found quite nice solution for that issue: I'm constructing `PendingIntent.getActivities()` and using one as fake/transparent/short lived to catch analytics.

Comment: @Kocus: I am surprised that your proposed technique works, but I am not complaining!  Nice find!